# Issues loading data into a BigQuery table using a cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I'm having issues trying to load a Data store backup into an existing table in BigQuery. I'm getting the following error:

`TypeError: bigquery.dataset(...).table(...).load is not a function`

I'm following one of the examples in the [BigQuery cloud Api](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/b0b9605ea6df8940477d8f4c14092012ab1e7d2f/samples/tables.js#L243) repo.

Not sure if I'm using this the wrong way, but what I'm trying to achieve is just have my cloud function update this BigQuery table from a Data Store dump, as opposed to delete and create daily - which seems counter productive and I was doing before.

Here is my code:

```
exports.processFile = function (event, callback) {

  const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
  const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  const bucketName = 'nyt-links-backup-dev';
  const filename = event.data.name;
  const tableId = 'links_data_tbl';
  const projectId = 'nyt-sartre-dev';

  // Instantiates clients
  const bigquery = new BigQuery({
    projectId: projectId,
  });

  const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: projectId,
  });

  const datasetId = 'sartre_sublink_dataset';
  const dataset = bigquery.dataset(datasetId);

  const metadata = {
    sourceFormat: 'AVRO',
  };     

  // Loads data from a Google Cloud Storage file into the table
  bigquery
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .table(tableId)
    .load(storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename), metadata)
    .then(results => {
      const job = results[0];

      // load() waits for the job to finish
      assert.equal(job.status.state, 'DONE');
      console.log(`Job ${job.id} completed.`);

      // Check the job's status for errors
      const errors = job.status.errors;
      if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
        throw errors;
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });
    callback();
};
```

Comment: What version of @google-cloud/bigquery are you using?

Comment: @Kat 0.9.6. That's why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are using a version of the BigQuery library that doesn't have the `load` function on `Table`s.  The `load` function was introduced in December 2017 in [version 0.12.0](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/releases/tag/v0.12.0) and was previously called `import`.